# What is the correct word to describe something that’s not in the center of a container?

Tags: single-word-requests

I took a picture of my new cushion but just realized the puff wasn’t in the right position when I took it. It’s not in the center of the container (?).

[image]

I want to say that the puff is a little bit too “high” but I’m not sure if “high” or “not in the center” is the correct expression for this.

How would a native speaker describe it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The puff is off-center.

> **off-center**.
> REGIONAL NOTE:   in BRIT, use off-centre.
>
> ADJECTIVE
>
> If something is off-center, it is not exactly in the middle of a space or surface.
> *Her mouth curved in an off-center smile.*
>
> [[Collins Dictionary]](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/off-center)